# pulling an excel sheet with =rand(between) in a Python while loop, and exporting results as .dbf

Tags: python, random, arcpy

To preface my question: I am very new to stack overflow, and relatively new to Python.

I am working on setting up a sensitivity analysis. I am working with 40 parameters that range from 0.1 - 1. My analysis requires simultaneously varying these parameters by +-0.1 roughly ~500 times. These values will then be fed into an ArcGIS tool. So, I need 500 sets of random values, for 40 parameters. These parameter values will then be compared to the output of the tool, to see which parameters the model is the most sensitive to. I've set up an Excel sheet that will randomly calculate these values each time it's opened, but the issue is that they need to be in .dbf format to be read by the ArcGIS tool.

I have set up a while loop (for 10 iterations to start, but will need to be ~500) and tried two different methods, in hopes that I could automate the process of calling the .xls to generate random numbers, and then exporting it to .dbf.

The first, arcpy.CopyRows_management correctly exported to .dbf. The issue was that the output was the exact same for each iteration, and instead of having values of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc, it contained values of 0.22, 0.37, 0.68 etc. It wasn't to the tenths, even though that was specified in the formulas in the .xls.

I also tried arcpy.TabletoTable_conversion but that was throwing the ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

I am open to all kinds of suggestions. Perhaps there is an easier way to randomly sample and export results to .dbf in Python. This does not need to be done using arcpy, but that is all I've really worked with. I really appreciate any help that is provided! Thanks for your time.

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    # Set run specific variables
    lulc = "D:\\SARuns\\lulc_nosoils_rand.xls\\lulc_nosoils$"
    folder = "D:\\SARuns"

    print "Reading lulc"

    newlulc = "D:\\SARuns\\lulc_nosoils_rand"+str(i)+".dbf"

    print "Reading newlulc"

    # Copy rows is copying it to a dbf, but the values inside 
    # are the same for each run. And, none are correct.    
    arcpy.CopyRows_management(lulc, newlulc)

    # Table to table should work. But isn't.    
    # arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(lulc, folder, newlulc)

    print "Converting table"    
    i+= 1
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a little confused, are you creating abunch of random numbers in excel, reading them in python and then exporting them?  Why not just create them in Python directly?

Comment: Can you try to explain what the end result of this will be?

Comment: Hi - thanks for your responses! The 40 parameters have set values, and are based on landcover suitability to provide habitat. So, N1 = 0.6, while N2 = 0.8 (and so on up until N = 40). The random values for N1 could be 0.5, 0.6 or 0.7. The random values for N2 could be 0.7, 0.8, 0.9. Does that help? And, Hydra IO, the end result of this would be 500 .dbf files with values that ranged between +- 0.1 for all 40 parameters. Each .dbf would be different.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating values in Excel you will always get all decimals. Even if you specify the numer format to 1 decimal, the whole number is still there. So I assume that is why you do not get the "exact numbers" with one decimal. Apply a round function to get one decimal only.

Copy rows does only copy the values out of your dbf, it does not open Excel to call that formula calculating a new random value.

So you will either have to calculate the random values in Python and create dBase Output or you need to actually open up an Excel instance - wich shoult trigger your new random values - and save that excel sheet as dBase.

Maybe populating an ArcMap table with your values using [CalculateField_management](http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000) and exporting that data to dBase would work, i.e. with something like this:

```
     arcpy.TableToDBASE_conversion(tableName, outPath)
```